# How to script warm up of CloudService instances in Azure?

Tags: c#, azure, application-warmup

I have a CloudService Classic Application with 2 instances which I will call bob_app_001 and bob_app_002, each BobApp has 5 instances in it.

The app is a c# Api which has an endpoint that we use for monitoring on ~/ping.

I currently deploy by taking one of the services out of Traffic Manager, letting traffic drain off, then VIP swapping the staging to Production slots, then re-adding to Traffic Manager. The issue here is that the first few request are always slow as the service spins itself up. I am trying to avoid this by spinning up all the web related stuff by hitting the ping endpoint before dropping the pool back into rotation.

How do I script getting all the app's urls from bob_app_001, which I can then loop through calling Invoke-WebRequest for each of them, on the ping endpoint to warm the service before I drop it back into the TrafficManager after VIP swap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getting all the app's urls from bob_app_001`
This will be the tricky part, especially without reaching inside the app and exposing the URLs somehow (depending on how your routing is set up)

I'd suggest using `Application Initialization Module` instead.

To enable the module you need to create an `applicationInitialization` section in web.config where you define the url to be hit for the initialization task to begin.

```
<system.webServer>  
  <applicationInitialization>  
    <add initializationPage="/app/init" />  
  </applicationInitialization>  
<system.webServer>
```

Then a lightweight controller to do you initialisation in:

```
public class InitController : ApiController
{
    [Route("/app/init")]
    public IHttpActionResult Index()
    {
        //do your initialisation / warmup here

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

I've left any notion of security out of this example, but it'd be best to restrict access to `/app/init` from within the application (and only run once)

Once setup, the swap operation between deployment slots will be completed *afte*r the code under "app/init" url is finished.

Comment: is the solution for cloud service or app service?